# why when I am connecting my USB device, this opens my settings above my app

Tags: android, android-usb

I am trying to connect my USB device to my phone via type-c
After creating the connection I get a strange behavior the app opens settings over my app and I have to click back to return my app ..

I am using felHR85:UsbSerial library.

I test it on android version 10

thanks.

```
try{
   usbSerialPort = UsbSerialDevice.createUsbSerialDevice(usbDevice,connection)
   if(usbSerialPort != null){
    if(usbSerialPort!!.open()){
       usbSerialPort?.setBaudRate(BAUD_RATE)                                    
       usbSerialPort?.setFlowControl(UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF)
       usbSerialPort?.setDataBits(UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8)
       usbSerialPort?.setStopBits(UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1)
       usbSerialPort?.setParity(UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE)
       usbSerialPort?.read(callback)
  }
 }
}catch (e:Exception){
 e.printStackTrace()
}
```